# Convert Binary Data from dataframe column

Tags: python, database, dataframe, clickhouse, binary-data

I load a table from a Clickhouse database into my python dataframe. One of the column contain binary data. How can i convert this binary data into text/readable format

Comment: Which data type for field do you have on ClickHouse database side?

Comment: It is of string type column and it stores binary object

Answer (score 0):

There may be a way to convert...but it depends heavily on the source type of the column. What was it that was binary encoded, what does it represent, etc.

A list of type conversion functions is available at:

https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/type-conversion-functions